# How to handle a missing file in a U-SQL EXTRACT statement?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have the following `EXTRACT` statement that grabs the data from both a staging file and the production file:

```
DECLARE @staging  string = "/staging/events.csv";
DECLARE @production string = "/production/events.csv";

@events =
        EXTRACT dimensionId         string
              , tenantId            string 
              , internalEntityId    long
              , name                string
              , modifiedTimestamp   DateTime
        FROM @staging, @production
        USING Extractors.Csv();
```

The statement will fail if either one of the two files is missing, which causes the whole `Azure Data Factory` pipeline to fail:

[image: Input stream(s) don't exist]

**Question**

How can I gracefully handle a missing file in a `U-SQL` `EXTRACT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I can qualify this as "Gracefully" but at least it does the trick.

I can use the [FILE.EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/metadata/file/file-exists) statement to test the presence of the file beforehand and choose to include it or not:

```
DECLARE @staging  string = "/staging/events.csv";
DECLARE @production string = "/production/events.csv";

IF FILE.EXISTS(@production) == true THEN
 @events =
     EXTRACT    dimensionId         string
              , tenantId            string 
              , internalEntityId    long
              , name                string
              , modifiedTimestamp   DateTime
        FROM @staging, @production
        USING Extractors.Csv();
ELSE
@events =
     EXTRACT    dimensionId         string
              , tenantId            string 
              , internalEntityId    long
              , name                string
              , modifiedTimestamp   DateTime
        FROM @staging
        USING Extractors.Csv();
END;
```